# Shader performance data maybe unavailable due to deployment target older than device version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

In a nutshell, I just want to know if I should be concerned about this issue:

**runtime: GPU Frame Capture**:

> Shader performance data maybe unavailable due to deployment target
>   older than device version

The device I am using is running iOS 12.0, and when I had the app set to target iOS 12, this issue was not appearing.

However, after I changed the app's target to 11.4, this appeared.

Based on my reading of it, and the performance of my app following the change, I do not think this is of any real concern and just exists to alert me that there *could* be problems obtaining shader performance data.

Short of testing against an 11.4 device, is there anything I can or even should, do to remove it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you really don't want to see this prompt, you can close it as shown below.

[image: Click here to see the picture]

You can find the above screenshot view on Products -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Comment: Thanks @JMCoder. Just one suggestion would be to mention how you got to the scheme editor, as some future users may not recognize this screen and could benefit from the assistance.

Comment: Should he be concerned or not. The answers does not answer that question at all ?

Comment: @Hope You raise a valid point, but I have since followed up here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools/enabling_frame_capture where Apple discusses this in detail. The gist is that this tool is purely for debugging purposes.