# Shader performance data maybe unavailable due to deployment target older than device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ios12

I'm getting one problem in my Xcode 10 and iOS 12. See my problem is:

**GPU Frame Capture**

**Shader performance data maybe unavailable due to deployment target older than device version**

See my screen shot

[image: This is my Screen shot]

This is happen in only iOS 12. Which means...

In my Xcode Deployment Target:9.0, 
In my iPhone OS is : iOS 12 (**Now problem came.**)

But when i run in Xcode 10 and iOS 11.4 it's fine.

Comment: I get the same error as well, very strange 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shader performance data maybe unavailable due to deployment target older than device version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509223/shader-performance-data-maybe-unavailable-due-to-deployment-target-older-than-de)

Comment: @pckill it's not duplicate, the question is same but the problem is different... Have you any idea about this problem...

Comment: @iOS did you solve this? I have same problem..

Comment: @ bezoadam No...

Comment: @iOS, what do you mean? The problem is exactly the same as well

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem, but a suggestion, that you could get more Shader performance data if you switch your deployment target to iOS 12.

You could switch to iOS 12 only during shader profiling, and put it back when it's done.

Comment: Then you could read about it, right there on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278392/what-does-deployment-target-mean